# jQuery-Mobile: ajax request stops working after changePage failure

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

I am presently developing a web application with jQuery mobile. However, I found that when a "changePage" fails, I can no longer send ajax requests.  After the failure, all ajax requests return an error.  Here's the code executed when the submit button on the form is clicked (it's a basic user login screen):

```
// Event when user click the Submit login button
$('#submitLogin').on("click", function () {

        // submit the user credentials to the server
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./LogUser",
            data: {
                EmployeeID: $('#EmployeeID').val(),
                EmployeePIN: $('#EmployeePIN').val()
            },
            dataType: "text",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            error: function (rqst, text, thrownError) {
                $('#dlg-login-error-message').text(thrownError);
                $('#dlg-login-error-popup').popup("open");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "Success") {
                    $.mobile.changePage("./LoadScreen/Menu");
                }
                else {
                    $('#dlg-login-error-message').text(data);
                    $('#dlg-login-error-popup').popup("open");
                }
            }
        });

    return false;
});
```

If the post itself fails, I can resubmit without problem.  If the .mobile.changePage fails, a "page not found" is displayed, but I am not able to resubmit, ajax no longer making request to the server and jumping directly to the error callback with a "not found" error.

I am guessing the problem comes from the fact that jQuery mobile uses AJAX request to load pages, and that somehow, ajax calls are getting mixed up somewhere.

I did more tests, even intercepted the pageloadfailed event, but nothing works.  After the page change failure, AJAX calls no longer sends anything to the server and jump automatically to the error callback function.

I tried with async=false, same problem.  I tried debugging jQuery-mobile, but I am still not able to find the "changePage" function itself ( the .code is quite confusing ).

I just spent the last two days trying to figure out a way to resolve this and I am seriously thinking of using something else than jQuery-mobile for our development.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for my problem, but I do not know the full impact of this solution yet.

To prevent the problem, I had to set the "pushStateEnabled" configuration option to "false".

So if you find yourself with the same problem, try putting the following in a script right before the loading of the "jQuery-mobile" script.

```
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    });
```

Example:

```
<!-- Load the script for jQuery -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

<!-- Set default for jQuery-Mobile, before it is actually loaded -->
<script>

    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    });

</script>

<!-- Load the script for jQuery-Mobile -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

Comment: The workaround does not always work.  In one of the page, the changePage failure corrupts AJAX and I can no longer make calls to the server. jQuery/jQuery Mobile seems to cripple AJAX calls after a changePage failure.